# xpath: decipher this xpath?

Tags: xpath

what does this xpath mean ? can someone decipher this ?

```
//h1[following-sibling::*[1][self::b]]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Select every `h1` element (in the document of the context node) that is immediately followed by a `b` element (with no other intervening element, though there may be intervening text).

Breaking it down:

```
//h1
```

Select every `h1` element that is a descendant of the root node of the document that contains the context node;

```
[...]
```

filter out any of these `h1` elements that don't meet the following criteria:

```
[following-sibling::*[1]...]
```

such that the first following sibling element passes this test:

```
[self::b]
```

self is a `b` element. Literally, this last test means, "such that when I start from the context node and select the self (i.e. the context node) subject to the node test that filters out everything except elements named `b`, the result is a non-empty node set."

Comment: very well explained. Thanks +1